# Is a marriage valid if couples got married invalidly?

Tags: catholicism, marriage

One of the grounds for nullity is "Insufficient Use of Reason" according to [Archiodiocese of Atlanta](https://archatl.com/offices/metropolitan-tribunal/grounds-of-marriage-nullity/).

> ...or black-out states (caused by alcoholic intoxication, drug use, or
>   seizure disorder)...

Now, if a couple gets married and one of them is intoxicated to the state that meets the criteria for invalidity. Is this marriage invalid in the eyes of God even if the couple believe they got married and stay together for the rest of life?

Or if a couple gets married because they are expecting a baby. They might claim they aren't marrying freely but for the sake of a child, or under the social pressure they choose it. Does this make the wedding vows invalid in the eyes of God even though they end up living together for the rest of their life?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking whether a marriage is valid if it's invalid (i.e. if it meets the grounds for invalidity), which makes no sense. What am I missing?

Comment: @MattGutting, yes. Is marriage valid in the eyes of God if it's invalid according to the definition?

Comment: That still makes no sense. "Valid according to the definition" *means* "valid in the eyes of God".

Comment: @MattGutting, I said INVALID. Don't twist my words. If something is invalid according to the definition it doesn't mean it's  not valid in the eyes of God. But since you are just downvoting I will remove the question.

Comment: The link to the Atlanta diocese is full of ideas for couples seeking an annulment. But OP is asking about couples who stay together, and presumably have no intention of seeking an annulment. It isn't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: I haven't voted the question up or down. But I'm still not sure how it's possible to distinguish "invalid in the eyes of the Church" and "invalid in the eyes of God". I may have an idea though. Maybe.

Comment: The question presupposes a distinction between "invalid" and "invalid in the eyes ofGod."  I'm not aware of any such distinction (and it seems other commenters aren't either), so it would be good to clarify what you have in mind. In general, I believe that whatever God thinks is the case is really the case; that is, I see no difference between God's opinion and reality.

Comment: @MattGutting, think of it a different way. Imagine a couple seeking an annulment. After some time a bishop calls and tells them they got approved for an annulment. Which means the bishop agrees the marriage never happened.  But the couple changes their mind in the meantime and don't want an annulment anymore and wants to stay together. What now? Was the marriage valid or not? Will they have to remarry?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, you say it like everything is black and white. "Reality" doesn't always reflect reality because we can't see into people's heart. If you go to confession and hide your sins you won't be forgiven even if a priest gives you an absolution.

Comment: That's trivial. If the bishop agrees the marriage was invalid, then it's invalid. I don't think there's an "invalid in the eyes of God" separate from "invalid in the eyes of the Church". Certainly not for marriages entered into in the Catholic Church.

Comment: @MattGutting so if the couple refuse to accept the decree of an annulment their marriage isn't valid anymore?

Comment: There are thousands of marriages that could be annulled according to the definition but because couples don't seek an annulment it will never be. Does it mean these marriages are valid?

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by distinguishing "reality"  from reality.  I was referring to just one reality, which includes all the facts (including the secrets in  our hearts) and which is known perfectly by God.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  "reality" from reality means exactly what the annulments are trying to solve. The sacraments never happened even though the celebrating priest said that they did.

Comment: In the situation you mentioned, I  see just one reality, namely that no sacrament took place. If the priest, the groom, the bride,and all onlookers thought that a sacrament took place, so what? Unlike God, people can hold erroneous opinions.

Comment: Coming up with an answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass well, it matters if someone lives in a lie, you don't think? I got an answer already so I don't want to extend these comments anymore.

Comment: @Grasper *But the couple changes their mind in the meantime*  It doesn't work that way. For an annulment process to arrive at a decree, the couple first have to produce a divorce decree. The "change their mind" will not arise. As to *Does it mean these marriages are valid?*  Marriage possesses the favor of law; therefore, in a case of doubt, the validity of a marriage must be upheld **until the contrary is proven**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To say that a marriage is invalid is to say that there was an obstacle (technically, an *impediment*) which prevents the couple from actually being married (not just from "being married in the eyes of the Church"). Some of these obstacles are matters of divine law—for example, canon 1091 section 1:

> In the direct line of consanguinity marriage is invalid between all ancestors and descendants, both legitimate and natural.

This is a statement given by God ([Deuteronomy 23:1](http://www.usccb.org/bible/deuteronomy/23:1)). As such, it is part of the [natural law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_law), binding on all people.

There are other impediments which are purely ecclesiastical in nature. In other words, they were created specifically by the Church, not by God. For example, canon 1083 section 1:

> A man before he has completed his sixteenth year of age and a woman before she has completed her fourteenth year of age cannot enter into a valid marriage.

God never specified exact ages before which a man or a woman couldn't marry (although it is clear that one can't get married at an arbitrarily young age). But the Church has decided that sixteen and fourteen years are reasonable age limits, and legislated accordingly.

Impediments which are matters of divine law are applicable to all people, whether Catholic or not—a marriage between a non-Christian man and his mother would still be invalid. But what about impediments that are ecclesiastical?

It seems unfair to apply rules that were specifically created by the Catholic Church to those outside the Church; and indeed, though the impediments of divine origin are binding on those outside the Church, they are so not because they are canon law, but because they are natural law. The Church just has specific implementations of them in canon law.

For a couple outside the Church, then, as long as a marriage is performed in accordance with natural law, and with the law of the land, it is a naturally valid marriage. In this case it is possible that the couple are subject to some ecclesiastical impediment, but still naturally validly married.

In the case of a marriage involving at least one Catholic, however, the case is different. God has given the Church authority to make these laws and to bind them on all Catholics. Thus, if the couple have ignored an impediment listed in canon law, their marriages are *in fact* invalid.

On the other hand, as canon law (1060) states:

> Marriage possesses the favor of law; therefore, in a case of doubt, the validity of a marriage must be upheld until the contrary is proven.

In other words, if no one is asked whether a given marriage is invalid, or if an investigation is ongoing into its validity, it is presumed valid unless proved otherwise. This means that there may be some marriages which are presumed valid but are in fact invalid. The reverse, however, is not the case, at least for a Catholic marriage: **there are no marriages which are in fact valid ("in God's eyes") though found invalid (by a marriage tribunal)**.

To address a couple of comments: If the diocesan marriage tribunal determines that a marriage is invalid, but the couple does not accept the decree of nullity, the marriage is still invalid, as stated above. And (again as stated above) if the validity of the marriage is never investigated—if the couple does not seek an annulment—it is still possible for the marriage to be invalid: but the Church is under the obligation to treat it as valid.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. I was trying to understand Pope's Francis reasoning behind his Amoris Laetitia, where he says(not directly): "acts, such as adultery, can be permitted and even willed by God". But from your answer above I can see that these acts in the eyes of God might not be adulterous because the first marriages were not valid. https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/amoris-laetitia-is-a-ticking-atomic-bomb-set-to-obliterate-all-catholic-mor

Comment: @Grasper If the Pope said (even indirectly) that any sinful act can be willed by God, he would be committing heresy. But that's matter for another question.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yeah that makes more sense. I was trying to preserve the wording of the previous statement, but I agree it's not quite accurate. Thanks!

Comment: @MattGutting Glad to be of help. Nice answer.

Comment: @MattGutting Good answer. But it isn't correct that there cannot be a marriage hold invalid by tribunal but in fact valid. We try to have highest certainty before making a decision, but human tribunals will make mistakes. The tribunals don't decide with infallible authority.